# Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class JPA

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char:

 SELECT NEW com.classes.applicant.ApplicantEntry(app.indSsn, app.indivName, app.indAddrLocTx,app.indAddrCityNm,app.indAdrStateAb,app.indAddrZipCd, app.phoneNr,app.workPhoneNr) FROM TApplicant app WHERE app.indSsn = :ssn
```

The class Constructor is correct:

```
public ApplicantEntry(String indSsn, String indivName, String indAddrLocTx, String indAddrCityNm, String indAdrStateAb, String indAddrZipCd,
                                 String phoneNr, String workPhoneNr) {
        this.indSsn = indSsn;
        this.indivName = indivName;
        this.indAddrLocTx = indAddrLocTx;
        this.indAddrCityNm = indAddrCityNm;
        this.indAdrStateAb = indAdrStateAb;
        this.indAddrZipCd = indAddrZipCd;
        this.phoneNr = phoneNr;
        this.workPhoneNr = workPhoneNr;

    }
```

And the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_APPLICANT", schema = "APP")
public class TApplicant implements Serializable, Applicant {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "IND_SSN", columnDefinition = "CHAR")
    private String indSsn;
```

I do not understand why it is complaining about it is expecting all strings when it is recieving all strings.

I am running the query in intellij's persistence tool.

Full query in Repository:

```
@Query("SELECT NEW com.classes.applicant.ApplicantEntry(app.indSsn, app.indivName, "
           +"app.indAddrLocTx,app.indAddrCityNm,app.indAdrStateAb,app.indAddrZipCd, app.phoneNr,app.workPhoneNr) "
           +"FROM TApplicant app "
           +"WHERE app.indSsn = :ssn ")
    ApplicantEntry getApplicantEntry(@Param("ssn") String ssn);
```

Comment: It is working now. Just cleaned my cache in my IDE and everything was happy. Hate it when it is things like that!

Comment: I faced the same issue in my other projects, after making the constructor 'public' this issue solved.

Answer (score 6):

Note for anyone using Lombok, the physical ordering of the fields in your class determines the order of your constructor parameters. The physical ordering of your class fields must match the ordering of the SELECT clause.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Thing {
  private String name;
  private Date birthday;
}

// not the same as...

@AllArgsConstructor
public class Thing {
  private Date birthday;
  private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `ApplicantEntry` constructor has 8 parameters while there are only 6 fields in the query.
2. The query doesn't look like correct jpa query. I think it should be

   ```
   SELECT NEW org.classes.applicant.ApplicantEntry(
       app.indSsn,                     
       app.adnlPhysExamCd,
       app.adnlPhysExamDt,
       app.adultDepnQy,
       app.adultDepnQy,
       app.advRankRsnCd,
       'placeholder',
       'placeholder'
       ) 
   FROM ApplicantEntry app WHERE app.indSnn = :ssn
   ```

Comment: No I have 8, that must have been a cut ans paste error. I correct my comment. I am still getting the same results.

Comment: @Drew1208 Try to add `COALESCE` expression for every field, i.e. `app.indSsn` replace with `COALESCE(app.indSsn, '')` and so on. Sometimes Hibernate is unable to locate appropriate constructor if there is null value in result set.